# Glide into Error while saving image into BITMAP

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-glide

```
          Bitmap bitmap;
```

String leo= "MY LINK FOR IMAGE"

bitmap = Glide.with(show_wallpaper.this).load(leo).into(bitmap);
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(show_wallpaper.this);
try {
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (IOException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Muhammad Umar . I advice you to read [this article (How to ask)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) just before you post a question.

Answer (score 0):

Glide has a listener from which you can get Image as Bitmap.

```
 Glide.with(context)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(imgUrl)
        .listener(object : RequestListener<Bitmap?> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(
                e: GlideException?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<Bitmap?>?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                log("Image failed to load")
                return false
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(
                resource: Bitmap?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<Bitmap?>?,
                dataSource: DataSource?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                /**
                 * @param resource is your bitmap
                 * paas the same into
                 * wallpaperManage.setBitmap(resource)
                 */
                return false
            }
        }).submit()
```